# Is it possible to change settings depending on the user's appstore? (iPhone app)

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I want to submit an universal iOS app and depending on the country I want to make some minor changes (Images, titles). Can I do it by relating this issue with the appstore that the user downloaded the app from?

Thank you and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot tell from which App Store country an app was downloaded.

You have to localize your app based on the language set on the users device.

I would recommend you checkout a few of the Localization videos from WWDC: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=244 (requires login)

Also, to determine the locale for a user's device, look at this dcoumentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Perfect. It solves my problem. So I just have to determine which language is set on the user's device and it's location to set the right settings in the app. Thank you very much @runmad

Comment: Yup. Basically you need to localize the app. I'm in Canada and I know a lot of people who download apps from the US store. I've also downloaded apps from the Danish store before, but you cannot assume that the person speaks the language from the country specific to the App Store. But you can assume to display the correct data (dates, button titles, etc.) as well as images based on the language set on the users device. Localization can be tedious but it pays off and users love it :)